# Validate Nested Array in laravel API Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cbJF.jpg)i want to validate **$request->form_data['bench_id'];** field in laravel API Controller usinfg below getvalidator function but when i pass null to bench_id exception throw an error **"Undefined index: bench_id"**

**My Validation function**

```
 protected function getValidator(Request $request)
    {
      $rules = [
        'form_data.*.bench_id' => 'nullable'
        ];

        return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
    }
```

[My form data input values here showing in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cbJF.jpg)

Comment: please include input data format too.

Comment: `  <div class="form-group bench-div-hide">
                            <label for="restaurent-bench-id">Bench Number: </label>
                            <input type="text" name="bench_id" id="bench_id" value="" class="sm-form-control" />
                        </div>`

Comment: do `dd($request->all());` and include it in question itself.

Comment: check my answer, it should work for you.